# Makefile misinterprets gcc version for Intel Pin on Fedora 22

Tags: c, gcc, makefile, intel, fedora

I just installed Intel Pin on my Fedora 22 machine, and I tried to run the makefile in `/source/tools` using `make`. When I run it, though, I get the following two errors repeated multiple times:

```
error: #error This kit requires gcc 3.4 or later
error: #error The C++ ABI of your compiler does not match the ABI of the pin kit.
```

However, my gcc version is

```
gcc version 5.1.1 20150618 (Red Hat 5.1.1-4) (GCC)
```

so I'm a bit confused about what's going on. How would I fix this?

Comment: I think you need to post whatever configuration test is in that makefile that is failing, for anyone to be able to figure it out

Answer (score 3):

Commenting out the offending lines in `source/include/pin/compiler_version_check2.H`
 seems to have done the trick for me:

```
#if !defined(__GXX_ABI_VERSION) || CC_USED_ABI_VERSION != __GXX_ABI_VERSION
#error The C++ ABI of your compiler does not match the ABI of the pin kit.
#endif
```

and

```
#if CC_USED_ABI_VERSION != __GXX_ABI_VERSION
#error This kit requires gcc 3.4 or later
#endif
```

Answer (score 2):

I came across the same problem. GCC 5.1 introduced a new ABI that is no longer compatible with gcc-3.4+. I would recommend you to download the newer version of pin, which compiles nicely with newer version of gcc.

Another solution would set the macro _GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI to 0, so that your compiler will use the older ABI. There are some Makefile configurations under PIN directories where you can set CXX flags for the PIN tools.

More on the dual ABI for gcc: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/using_dual_abi.html

Newer version of PIN can be found here https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/pintool-downloads. The latest release, was on Mar 24, 2016.

Answer (score 0):

*This* error:

```
error: #error The C++ ABI of your compiler does not match the ABI of the pin kit.
```

is probably totally right, but I'm guessing that the other error message makes a silly assumption — that any ABI mismatch is because your system has a ABI *older* than 3.4. But, this goes both directions, and now, you have an ABI mismatch because of course GCC 5.1 is much *newer*.

Some background at Fedora Magazine: [GCC 5 in Fedora (What’s an ABI, and what happens when we change it?)](http://fedoramagazine.org/gcc-5-in-fedora-whats-an-abi-and-what-happens-when-we-change-it/)